# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: connection refused

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, connection

I am trying to open a URL but it gives the following error in Centos 8.

Failed to open connection to "session" message bus:

```
Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
    1634647277057   mozrunner::runner       
INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "--headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile3nLOd3"
Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

Running without a11y support!

I tried creating xvfb service, nothing worked.

Comment: describe more share codes etc